# creating a dynamic WHERE clause in a MySQL stored routine

Tags: mysql

Any help with this problem would be good as it's driving me crazy. 
A table in my MYSQL database contains details of monetry coins
although there seem to be lots of dynamic WHERE clauses out there,
i've searched dozens none seem to cater for a variable which is 
missing.

```
TABLE coin (
  coinID smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  coinCountry smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  coinDenom smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  coinMinted smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  coinImageLocation varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  coinPgeTitle varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (coinID)
)
```

I want a dynamic 'WHERE' clause in a stored routine which accepts three parameters
one of the parameters is mandatory and will always have a value, the other two are discretionary
and will either have a value or not

I have written this stored routine and somewhere within lurks the problem

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procFilterCoins`
(

/*******************************************************

Proc     :  Filter the coins returned by adjusting the WHERE Clause.

IN   :  iCountry (The CountryID) a mandatory value

IN   :  iDenom (The DenominationID) a discretionary value

IN   :  iMinted (The year minted) a discretionary value

OUT      :  filtered coins recordset

********************************************************/

IN iCountry int(11), 

IN iDenom int(11), 

IN iMinted int(11)
)

BEGIN

/* somewhere to hold our where clause*/

DECLARE strWhere varchar(100);


set strWhere = '((coinCountry = ';

IF iDenom > 0 and iDenom IS NOT NULL THEN

    set strWhere = concat(strWhere, iCountry, ") AND (coinDenom = ", iDenom, ')');

ELSE

    set strWhere = concat(strWhere, iCountry, ')');

END IF;


IF iMinted > 0 and iMinted IS NOT NULL THEN

    set strWhere = concat(strWhere, " AND (coinMinted = ", iMinted, '))');

ELSE

    set strWhere = concat(strWhere, ')');
END IF;


/*Extract the records via prepared view*/
SELECT * FROM vAllcoins WHERE + strwhere;


END
```

I have tested with the following data using **MySQL Workbench 5.2.46.CE**

call procfiltercoins(18,null,1948);
Produces... WHERE ((coinCountry = 18) AND (coinMinted = 1948));
NO records returned

call procfiltercoins(103,4,1948,@out);
Produces...

```
WHERE ((coinCountry = 103) AND (coinDenom = 4) AND (coinMinted = 1948));
```

NO records returned

call procfiltercoins(18,2,null,@out);
Produces...

```
WHERE ((coinCountry = 18) AND (coinDenom = 2));
```

NO records returned

I have replicated all of this in an Access database with no problems

Answer (score 5):

Try using a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM vAllcoins WHERE ",strwhere);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Not sure what you want to do with the results of the query. Put it in a view maybe?

```
SET @query = CONCAT("CREATE VIEW myView as SELECT * FROM vAllcoins WHERE ",strwhere);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I've rejigged the stored routine and come up with the following which works.

`CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE procOtherFilter(
/******************************
Proc :  Filter the coins returned by adjusting the WHERE Clause.
IN   :  iCountry (The CountryID) a mandatory value
IN   :  iDenom (The DenominationID) a discretionary value
IN   :  iMinted (The year minted) a discretionary value
OUT  :  filtered coins recordset
*******************************/
IN iCountry int(11), 
IN iDenom int(11), 
IN iMinted int(11)
)
BEGIN
/* If we only have the countryID it will always be there as it's mandatory */
IF (iDenom IS NULL) AND (iMinted IS NULL) THEN
    SELECT * FROM vAllcoins WHERE (coinCountry = iCountry);
/* If the denomination is missing use the minted date */
ELSEIF iDenom IS NULL THEN
    SELECT * FROM vAllcoins WHERE (coinCountry = iCountry) AND (coinMinted = iMinted);
/* If the minted date is missing use the denomination */
ELSEIF iMinted IS NULL THEN
    SELECT * FROM vAllcoins WHERE (coinCountry = iCountry) AND (coinDenom = iDenom);`

END IF;

END

Thanks to everyone who viewed